# How to Download file from Active FTP Server using NSURLSession API as CFFTP API are deprecated from iOS 9?

Tags: ftp, ios9, nsurlsession, download, cfftp

I have a configured active server which is listed in white wash list of firewall.There is a file at some path on FTP server. How can I download them by using NSURLSession API?